# Visual Studio 2019 C++ Desktop application; How do I make a child window?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I successfully created an app with a main window, a title bar, and a menu structure.  Now I want to create a child window within the borders of the main window to handle one of the menu options. I did at least create the callback structure for the child window, whose function is "Connect."

In the interest of creating an infinitely flexible development protocol, MS has implemented a regime in which "this is an alias for that," and "this is a new version of an old function that does something better than in Windows 7."  I need, please, the seven-year-old's instruction, "Put this line here."  I promise that once the ball starts rolling, I'll see that it gets to the bottom of the hill.

Specifically: (a) Where and how do I register the class for the new window, as it seems to fit this framework?
(b) Where does the new CreateWindowW function go?

```
/**
 * @file       AD4951.cpp
 * @brief      Application for PC that polls Primera devices
 * @author     Robert Hadow
 * @date       April 2021
 * @par        Revision History:
 *
 *
**/

// AD4951.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "AD4951.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    Connect(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_AD4951, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_AD4951));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_AD4951));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_AD4951);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case ID_CONNECT:  // Robert


                break;
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

// Message handler for connect window.
INT_PTR CALLBACK Connect(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: There was a time when it was obvious to **any** developer that complex concepts require treatment in books. Apparently, you believe that the reference documentation were enough. This is not the case. Get Petzold's "Programming Windows". When done, you'll make sense of the reference documentation with ease.

Comment: Okay.  Appropriately dressed down. Do you want me to withdraw the question, or leave it as an example for others not to leave questions before they RTFM?

Comment: Win32 API is not easy as modern framework. You need to either read some books or start from workings code samples. **And even then, there are a lot of low level details to know**. When those API were ported to 32 bits almost 30 years ago, 16 MB of RAM was a lot of memory and CPU speed was below 100MHz. For most software, it does not make sense to directly write at that level (at least 10 time the effort for the UI part).

Comment: What are you talking about the new  `CreateWindowW` function. `CreateWindow` exists in both ANSI and Unicode version since Windows NT which is almost 30 years old now. The documentation explain `CreateWindow` and if there is important difference between the A and W version, there will be information about that. `CreateWindow` is in fact a macro depending on if your compile for ANSI or Unicode. I am not sure if under Windows 10 we can make an UTF-8 application yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where and how do I register the class for the new window

You can register the window class for the child window at anytime during program initialization. So inside the `MyRegisterClass` function is a perfectly fine place to do it.

> Where does the new CreateWindowW function go?

Best choice: you can simply invoke `CreateWindow` for the child windows in `WM_CREATE` of your main window.

Or you can invoke `CreateWindow` outside your child's windows proc immediately after the original `CreateWindow` call returns for the parent window.

Find a used copy of the [Petzold Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X) for classic Win32 programming.

Comment: *"Or you can invoke `CreateWindow` outside your child's windows proc"* - I'm not sure I understand. Are you suggesting there were a way to create a (child) window from within its window procedure? Obviously, the call to `CreateWindow` must **always** be outside the window procedure registered for any given window class.

Comment: @IInspectable - [This](https://imgur.com/a/vzElAdj) is what I am saying is possible.  The red square is a child window.

Comment: But you cannot create a child window from that child window's window procedure, which you seem to be suggesting. I mean, you cannot create **any** window from its own window procedure. No one is calling that window procedure, except for `CreateWindow`. Which implies that you are always invoking `CreateWindow` outside its window procedure.

Comment: @IInspectable - I really don't know what you are arguing about. The OP is asking, "where do I put my code to create a child window".  My answer: it in the `WM_CREATE` handler for the parent window or after the call to `CreateWindow` to instantiate the parent window."  There's a presumption that there's two separate window classes and two separate WndProcs, but it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: That's not what your answer says. Read the quote in my first comment.

Comment: I did buy a copy of Petzold.  Thanks.